# how to change title attribute with html content using jquery?

Tags: jquery, attributes, tooltip

I have this code for title attribute for tooltip.

```
title=" <div id=\'tooltip-row\'>
           <div class=\'tooltip-label\'>ID : </div> <div class=\'tooltip-value\'> '.$id.' </div>
        </div>

       <div id=\'tooltip-row\'>
           <div class=\'tooltip-label\'>X  : </div> <div class=\'tooltip-value\'> '.$x.' </div>
       </div>
              "
```

in php. and I want to replace the value of the ID inside the title attribute.
any idea? thanks!

Comment: use attr('title','your vaue')

Comment: yes I actually use that, but how can i replace the title with html content using juery. for example, I want to replace it with "<div id=\'tooltip-row\'>
           <div class=\'tooltip-label\'>ID : </div> <div class=\'tooltip-value\'> 100</div>
        </div>"